# Como puedo crear un metodo en el modelo que me devuelva el objeto que pertenece al parametro que le estoy pasando?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Soy nuevo en rails, quiero crear un medoto de clase en el modelo que me devuelva la rutina que pertenece a la persona que le estoy pasando y que se encuentre entre las fechas especificadas. Tengo esto

```
  class Routine < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :member,
    class_name: :Person,
    foreign_key: :member_id

  validates :member_id,
    presence: true

  validates :end_date,
    presence: true,
    if: :start_date

  validates :start_date,
    presence: true,
    if: :end_date

   def active_for(member)
    routine = member.routine
    today = Time.zone.today
    if routine.start_date >= today && routine.end_date <= today
      routine.last
      routine
    end
  end

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de agregar la consulta en el método de tu modelo `Routine`, podrías agregarlo en el de `Person`:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  # tu código...
  def active_routines
    routines.where(
      'routines.start_date >= :today AND routines.end_date <= :today', 
      today: Time.zone.today
    )
  end
end
```

así en vez de llamar a `Routine.active_for(member)`, llamarías a `member.active_routines`, lo cual, personalmente me suena mejor.

Comment: Definitivamente mejor opción poner el código donde pertenece (i.e. `Person`); incluso podrías dar un paso más adelante y agregar el `where` como un `scope` en `Routine`: `scope :active, -> { where(...) }` y luego, en el método `active_routines`, llamar `routines.active`.